# Silverlight Charting LineSeries - Add caption to the datapoint

Tags: silverlight, charts, caption

```
 <toolkit:Chart Title="Sales" Name="ChartSales">
                     <toolkit:Chart.Series>
                <toolkit:LineSeries
                            Title="Serie1" Name="LineSerie1"
                            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}"
                            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" />
                <toolkit:LineSeries
                            Title="Serie3" Name="LineSerie3"
                            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}"
                            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" />
```

I have created a chart with 10 lineseries, all working nicely. However there are so much data on this chart that I need the caption that show up when pointing over the datapoint to be more explicit than 1243. I need to see the date and the title of the LineSerie

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out combining these 2 links:

[Datapoint tooltip for silverlight chart toolkit](http://www.rajneeshnoonia.com/blog/2009/12/datapoint-tooltip-for-silverlight-chart-toolkit/)

[Silverlight Charting: Creating rich data point tooltips](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/12/charting-rich-tooltips/)